# Mistake in routing, how do you fix it?

Tags: reactjs

I need it redirected to a page with its index every time I click.  That is, for the url to be '/event/1', 'event/2' and so on. I tried to do something, but apparently because of the 'map', I'm not working properly. It turns out that if I have 3 times more elements in the map[1,2,3] than I need. I don't know how to do it any other way.

Help me, please. I'm still a rookie.

```js
class ShowCardDescription extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isToggleCard: true};
        this.handleClickCard = this.handleClickCard.bind(this);
    }


    handleClickCard() {
        this.setState({
            isToggleCard: !this.state.isToggleCard
        });
        this.props.handleClick()
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div class='main'>
        <section>
          {this.props.isToggleOn && <div className='element' onClick={this.handleClickCard}/>}
        </section>
        {!this.state.isToggleCard && <div className='content'>
        <div onClick={this.handleClickCard}>
            <p className='close'>close</p>
        </div>
        {this.props.children}</div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Description extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>some text here</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class MainContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isToggleOn: true
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn
        });
    }

    render() {
        return [1,2,3].map((index) => {
          return (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <div id="tabs-content">
                <Link to={'/event/' + index}>
                    <ShowCardDescription isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn} handleClick={this.handleClick}>
                      <Switch>
                        <Route path='/event/:index'>
                          <Description />
                          <Description />
                          <Description />
                        </Route>
                      </Switch>
                    </ShowCardDescription>
                  </Link>
                </div>
             </BrowserRouter>
        )
      })
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainContent />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: did you try `[1,2,3].map((index) => {` putting these inside `Link`, closest to the first usage?

Comment: Can you please write what it would look like? I don't get it.

Comment: I have posted the snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you were going for, so I just removed some duplication and did a little clean up.

I'm using memory router here as BrowserRouter doesn't work within stack overflow.

I'm passing the index through to elements to just give a visual of which elements exist.

In the ShowCardDescription, you didn't really need the Route as it was because you aren't even using the parameter or anything about the route, and you are rendering 3 different descriptions.

```
    <Route path='/event/:index'>
      <Description />
      <Description />
      <Description />
    </Route>
```

I changed it to this instead to make the Description component able to use that Route Props and to get rid of the duplication. Though if you need it to be duplicated, you can always modify Description, or duplciate this line.

```
<Route path="/event/:index" component={Description}/>
```

If you want props with the description and to use the route, you can use the [render function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func):

```
<Route path="/event/:index" render={(renderProps)=><Description {...renderProps} otherProp="hi" />}/>
```

If you want multiple components with the route props you can use:

```
<Route path="/event/:index" render={(renderProps)=><React.Fragment><Description {...renderProps} otherProp="hi" />
```

}/>

You can also wrap the Description with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) if you desire, which would let you use your initial:

```
 const WrappedDescription = withRouter(Description);

    <Route path='/event/:index'>
      <WrappedDescription otherProp="hi"/>
      <WrappedDescription />
      <WrappedDescription />
    </Route>
```

If you don't need to use the route at all,

```
<Description otherProp="hi"/>
<Description otherProp="hi2"/>
```

If you have an array with props to map over:

```
[{otherProp="hi",key:1},{otherProp="hi2",key:2}].map(data=><Description {...data}/>)
```

In short, there are many different ways to work with the props and rendering items.

Here's a working example with one of them:

```js
const { MemoryRouter, Link, Switch, Route } = ReactRouterDOM;

class ShowCardDescription extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleCard: true };
  }

  handleClickCard = () => {
    this.setState({
      isToggleCard: !this.state.isToggleCard,
    });
    this.props.handleClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="main">
        <section>
          {this.props.isToggleOn && (
            <div className="element" onClick={this.handleClickCard}>
              {this.props.idx}
            </div>
          )}
        </section>
        {!this.state.isToggleCard && (
          <div className="content">
            <div onClick={this.handleClickCard}>
              <p className="close">close</p>
            </div>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Description extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>some text here {this.props.match.params.index}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MainContent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isToggleOn: true,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MemoryRouter>
        <div id="tabs-content">
          {[1, 2, 3].map((index) => {
            return (
              <Link to={'/event/' + index}>
                <ShowCardDescription
                  idx={index}
                  isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn}
                  handleClick={this.handleClick}
                >
                  <Route path="/event/:index" component={Description}/>
                </ShowCardDescription>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainContent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.2.0/react-router-dom.min.js" integrity="sha256-D8mVu8eRkAsTYloDamogrsYZAjh6j+29tycpvfJaG68=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Everything works, but the url doesn't change. What's wrong?

Comment: You'll have to change MemoryRouter back to BrowserRouter. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/MemoryRouter

Comment: Thank you. And if I need to pass 'props', how do I do that? So that each DESCRIPTION has its own props.

Comment: `<Route path="/event/:index" render={renderProps=><Description {...renderProps} otherProp="hi"/>}/>` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: So, I have to write 5 similar lines of code for 5 'description'? If I do this, they are all displayed together on the page. I'm sorry for the stupid questions, I want to deal with it

Comment: I've added several examples of different ways you can render them. Including mapping over an array of configuration objects.

Comment: When I try to create several components and pass 'props' to them, they are all displayed. But I only need one. I did everything as you wrote it(

<Route path="/event/:index" render={renderProps=><React.Fragment><Description {...renderProps} name="hi"/><Description {...renderProps} name="hi2" /></React.Fragment>}/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214599/discussion-between-zachary-haber-and-jessica-cornish).

Answer (score 1):

Put these  [1,2,3].map(...) just before the `Links`.

```
render() {
          return (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <div id="tabs-content">
              {
                [1,2,3].map((index) => {
                  return (<Link to={'/event/' + index}>
                    <ShowCardDescription isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn} handleClick={this.handleClick}>
                      <Switch>
                        <Route path='/event/:index'>
                          <Description />
                          <Description />
                          <Description />
                        </Route>
                      </Switch>
                    </ShowCardDescription>
                  </Link>)
                 })

              }
                </div>
             </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
```

Comment: There's no mistake? 

[1,2,3]. map((index) => {

Comment: I didn't get you. Try this snippet once and let me know if it works.

Comment: Are the three `Links` getting created?

Comment: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214595/discussion-between-rahul-dwivedi-and-jessica-cornish).